# Curious flags in FPU command FCOMP and FCOMI

Tags: assembly, nasm, flags, fpu

I have a question about the behaviour of the flags in the fpu after doing the fcomp-Operation. 
The fpu-stack has no overflows, in both code snippets are the same values engaged in the comparison operations.

Why does this code work:

```
fldz                ;[0] 
fadd dword [esp+4]  ;[x]
fld1                ;[1][x]
fcomip st0, st1     ;compare 1, x
                    ;[x] because fcomip pops the 1
je xeins            ;falls x = 1: special routine
fld1                ;[1][x]
fxch st0, st1       ;[x][1]
fcomi st0, st1      ;compare x, 1
jc xinval           ;if x < 1 (carry = 1): special routine
```

And this code not?

```
fldz                ;[0] 
fadd dword [esp+4]  ;[x]
fld1                ;[1][x]
fcomip st0, st1     ;compare 1, x
                    ;[x] because fcomip pops the 1
je xeins            ;if x = 1: special routine
fld1                ;[1][x]
fcomip st0, st1     ;compare x, 1
jc xinval           ;if x < 1 (carry = 1): special routine
```

Comment: Define what _"does not work_ means. Maybe I missed something, but it looks to me like the only difference between those two snippets is that you removed the `fxch` in the second snippet. So the comparison before the `jc` is comparing the values in the opposite order in snippet 2 compared to snippet 1.

Comment: does not work meant: The code at xinval is not called
Thank you!